# Can someone help me understand whats happening with my batch program?(Menu/multi Option)

Tags: batch-file

Hello I am a programmer making a small little "Tool" That uses batch, I am running into a problem how ever..When Ever you put in a input, it just goes to the first option no matter what I do(or the user for that matter)

```
echo            1) File Explorer
echo.
echo            2) Terminal
echo.           
echo            3) Tools
echo.
echo            4) About
echo.
echo            5) Exit
::This is the Main Menu Input Stuff:::::::::::::::;::::
set /P Input = ">"
if /I %Input% EQU "1" goto :FileExplorer
if /I %Input% EQU "2" goto :Terminal
if /I %Input% EQU "3" goto :Tools
if /I %Input% EQU "4" goto :About
if /I %Input% EQU "5" goto :ExitQ
```

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong so any help will be good. Thanks 
A few more things, I have checked for spelling errors, And and have rewriten it with else statements but that just made it crash/exit.

Comment: Remove the quotes from the right side of the comparison.

Comment: Don't need the /I option either.  You are doing a numeric comparison not a string compare.

Comment: Ill try that right now. Ill get back to you if it works. If I remember correctly, I did that before but it still didn't work, I will try again though.

Comment: You also need to remove the spaces in your set command.  Otherwise it thinks the space is part of the variable name. `set /P Input= ">"`

Comment: Alright Ill try that to, I have to fix a crashing issue,

Comment: Closely related: [Batch if statements not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14207952) and [if statement not working batch (goes directly to else)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36781647).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if /I %Input% EQU "1" goto :FileExplorer
```

You need to include quotes since the comparison is literal (and the colon is not required)

```
 if /I "%Input%" EQU "1" goto FileExplorer
```

Batch simply charges on line after line until it's told to `goto` somewhere or reaches end-of-file, hence if *none* of your tests cause a branch via a `goto` then the next statement after `... equ "5"` will be executed. I'd warrant that the following command is your first option, `:fileexplorer`

As aschipfl points out, the space after `input` in `set` is significant and should be removed. Here's my standard blurb:

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"